# Why can't I scroll over a listView? I get the typic error `A RenderFlex overflowed by xx pixels on the bottom`

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and I am trying to avoid the scroll problem at the bottom. I wanted to use a `ListView` to scroll through a series of elements.
My question is, why am I getting the problem of `A RenderFlex overflowed by 94 pixels on the bottom.`? the element that exceeds these pixels is my `ListView`, but this element is supposed to have its own scroll inside it.

this is my code:

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          //here
          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
          new TextEditingController().clear();
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          body: SafeArea(
              child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.78,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(),
                            Expanded(
                                child: Container(
                              child: Container(),
                            ))
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[Container()],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        Container(
                            child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                SizedBox(width: 10),
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[(Container())],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                          ],
                        )),
                        Divider(
                          height: 50.0,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),

                        SizedBox(height: 35), //SingleChildScrollView
                        Container(
                          child: ListView(shrinkWrap: true, children: <Widget>[
                            Text("LOREM "),
                            Text("LOREM "),
                            Text("LOREM "),
                            Text("LOREM "),
                            Text("LOREM "),
                            Text("LOREM "),
                            Text("LOREM "),
                            Text("LOREM "),
                            Text("LOREM "),
                            Text("LOREM "),
                            Text("LOREM "),
                            Text("LOREM "),
                            Text("LOREM "),
                            Text("LOREM "),
                            Text("LOREM "),
                            Text("LOREM "),
                            Text("LOREM "),
                            Text("LOREM "),
                            Text("LOREM "),
                            Text("LOREM "),
                            Text("LOREM "),
                            Text("LOREM "),
                            Text("LOREM "),
                            Text("LOREM "),
                            Text("LOREM "),
                            Text("LOREM "),
                          ]),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
          ])),
        ),
      );
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Its because your container has a fixed height. Try removing the height and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my friend, when you want to use listview you must define height for the listview because listview takes unlimited height

Example:

```
Container(
height: 50,
child: ListView(shrinkWrap: true, children: <Widget>[
Text("LOREM "),
Text("LOREM "),
Text("LOREM "),
Text("LOREM "),
]),)
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but i don't understand why if i'm using  `SingleChildScrollView`, the same error occurs, the  `SingleChildScrollView` should prevent this error..

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your listview in Expanded or any such flexible widget(Flexible).